# How to access an old system disk attached via USB which has the same volume group id

Tags: lvm, mount

I've recently had to have the system disk in a remote server replaced, and the DC attached the old disk to a USB port. The problem is that CentOS was installed on both using all the defaults, and so now the output of `lvscan` is:

```
[root@IS-55825 /]# lvscan
  inactive          '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_home' [53.46 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_swap' [7.67 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_home' [53.24 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_swap' [7.89 GiB] inherit
```

`pvs` can tell the difference, but I can't figure out how to separate them in a way that I can just mount one of the old partitions to get some config information back:

```
[root@IS-55825 /]# pvs -v
    Using physical volume(s) on command line.
    Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
    Wiping internal VG cache
    Cache: Duplicate VG name vg_is55825: Existing KbuKYZ-yPtq-VI65-DlqY-e0j3-5Van-9UTe06 (created here) takes precedence over gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO
    Cache: Duplicate VG name vg_is55825: Existing KbuKYZ-yPtq-VI65-DlqY-e0j3-5Van-9UTe06 (created here) takes precedence over gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree DevSize PV UUID
  /dev/sda2  vg_is55825 lvm2 a--u 111.13g    0  111.13g QC5BPW-VdKx-dNnw-vSNm-cH6H-fZwB-HHXwFb
  /dev/sdd2  vg_is55825 lvm2 a--u 111.13g    0  111.13g LNSYx6-8DCv-u9CG-S1zv-vI20-fNIq-7BA8Le
```

It's `/dev/sdd2` that I'm after, but it won't mount directly:

```
[root@IS-55825 /]# mount /dev/sdd2 /oldsys
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

I tried `lvdisplay --select vg_uuid=LNSYx6-8DCv-u9CG-S1zv-vI20-fNIq-7BA8Le` but it gives no output, and that's as far as I got... Is there some way to get access to it?

Answer (score 2):

OK - I was able to fix this using `vgrename`. Firstly, running `lvscan -v`:

```
[root@IS-55825 ~]# lvscan -v
    Using logical volume(s) on command line.
    Cache: Duplicate VG name vg_is55825: Existing KbuKYZ-yPtq-VI65-DlqY-e0j3-5Van-9UTe06 (created here) takes precedence over gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO
    Cache: Duplicate VG name vg_is55825: Existing KbuKYZ-yPtq-VI65-DlqY-e0j3-5Van-9UTe06 (created here) takes precedence over gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO
    Cache: Duplicate VG name vg_is55825: Existing gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO (created here) takes precedence over KbuKYZ-yPtq-VI65-DlqY-e0j3-5Van-9UTe06
  inactive          '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_home' [53.46 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_swap' [7.67 GiB] inherit
    Cache: Duplicate VG name vg_is55825: Existing KbuKYZ-yPtq-VI65-DlqY-e0j3-5Van-9UTe06 (created here) takes precedence over gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_home' [53.24 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_is55825/lv_swap' [7.89 GiB] inherit
```

So I guessed the UUID `gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO` was the old disk. So I ran `vgrename`:

```
[root@IS-55825 ~]# vgrename gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO vg_oldsys
  Processing VG vg_is55825 because of matching UUID gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO
  Volume group "gVj6yw-hbls-RgTh-MKe3-saoW-KH3B-ggf2LO" successfully renamed to "vg_oldsys"
```

And then I was able to mount `/dev/vg_oldsys/lv-root`. Phew.